# Change the height of the title bar

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

**Question**: Can we change the height of the title bar displayed in [MahApps.Metro](https://mahapps.com/)?

**Details**: For instance, in the following XAML [example](https://mahapps.com/docs/guides/quick-start) from the MahApps team, I want to display the content `Deploy CupCake` - of the `TextBlock` - below the image of the CupCake. So I removed the `Orientation="Horizontal"` from the `StackPanel` in the following XAML. As shown in the snapshot below, the content `Deploy CupCake` is now showing below the image of CupCake - but it is hiding almost all of it. How can we make this content show all of it below the CupCake image?

**Snapshot of the Toolbar with MahApps.Metro**: Only about 10% of the content is showing below the image.

[image: Button in title bar with image and text below, which is cut off.]

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
                 xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 Title="MainWindow"
                 Width="800"
                 Height="450"
                 GlowBrush="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}"
                 ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
                 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                 mc:Ignorable="d">

  <mah:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
    <mah:WindowCommands>
      <Button Click="LaunchGitHubSite" ToolTip="Open up the GitHub site">
        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Width="22"
                                  Height="22"
                                  Kind="SocialGithubOctocat" />
      </Button>
    </mah:WindowCommands>
  </mah:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>

  <mah:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <mah:WindowCommands>
      <Button Click="DeployCupCakes" Content="Deploy CupCakes">
        <Button.ContentTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <iconPacks:PackIconModern Width="22"
                                        Height="22"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Kind="FoodCupcake" />
              <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Button.ContentTemplate>
      </Button>
    </mah:WindowCommands>
  </mah:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>

  <Grid>
    <!--  Your content  -->
  </Grid>
</mah:MetroWindow>
```

Comment: did you try with grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is better to use a to use a panel that distributes the **available space** among its content, like a `Grid`, to prevent cutting off content as with the `StackPanel`. Here, the data template defines a `Grid` with two rows, where the `TextBlock` scales to its desired size and the icon takes up the remaining available space. Also note the `HorizontalAlignment` of the icon, it is centered.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <iconPacks:PackIconModern Grid.Row="0"
                                Width="22"
                                Height="22"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Kind="FoodCupcake" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                 Margin="4 0 0 0"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Text="{Binding}" />
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The same result could also be achieved using a `DockPanel`, where the last child (in this case the icon) takes up the remaining available space, so the order of the defined controls is important.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <DockPanel>
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                 Margin="4 0 0 0"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Text="{Binding}" />
      <iconPacks:PackIconModern DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                Width="22"
                                Height="22"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Kind="FoodCupcake" />
   </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

In both cases you will get the result below, a button with a centered icon and a text below.

[image: MetroWindow with a button that has an icon with a text below it.]

To make the button more prominent, change the title bar height with the [`TitleBarHeight`](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Controls/MetroWindow.cs#L604) property.

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
         xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         Title="MainWindow"
         Width="800"
         Height="450"
         GlowBrush="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}"
         ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
         WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         TitleBarHeight="50">
```

[image: MetroWindow with a button that has an icon with a text below it (title bar height set to 50).]

Comment: It worked. Thank you for explaining the steps, as well.